# Celery with an ORM on its own

Tags: orm, celery

Currently i'm using Django and Celery for task execution. It's easy to use the ORM from Django in Celery while using SQS for the broker.

My question is, how can I continue with Celery separately without using Django ORM to access my MySQL database and still access SQS? I just want to access the data to handle tasks (getting users, etc).

I read the below:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#installing-celery

But this is more for making SQLAlchemy or Django the broker--which I don't want to do. I just want to access the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

http://prschmid.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-sqlalchemy-with-celery-tasks.html

It uses SQLAlchemy with Celery using RabbitMQ as the broker.